# Have wordpress as a module or extension in Yii

Tags: wordpress, yii

I would like to add a blog to a web site. Couldn't find any good blog extension for Yii, so I decided to just use Wordpress. (Please let me know if there's a better way)

I could just extract wordpress in the root folder and run it.

http://www.example.com/wordpress

However, the Yii framework has its index.php on root folder so I will have to make wordpress either a module or extension (I think) unless I put the Yii framework in a root/yiiFolder and use root/wordpress to separate the two.  Also, the main layout will have to be different than the Yii default main layout.  Otherwise, the blog will share the same header and footer structure of Yii.

Could someone give me an example on how Yii framework call a *non-yiiframework* site?

Comment: you would probably be better off putting them in separate folders, one could even be in the root folder and the other a separate folder. it would also theoretically be possible to use the same index.php file and choose which bootstrap (yii or wp) file, but that seems like it would be asking for trouble.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I'm also trying to add a blog to a Yii website. There's a Yii extension for "forum" but not for "blog", which is pretty odd...I'd think it's a common task that someone would have implemented as an extension by now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having the following error:

> include(Translation_Entry.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

then you need to disable Autoload, for example like this:

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
$wp=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../wp-load.php'; 
require_once($wp);
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://wpengineer.com/1038/embed-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress/ - here is described how to call wordpress functions from outside wordpress. I tried the same thing from Yii layout and now I'm facing strange error. `include(Translation_Entry.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. I need to look a little more into this.

Other than that - this solution (if you manage to configure it) should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can include wordpress as a library, and `require_once 'wp_config.php'` in index.php. Then you can call wordpress function directly.